# how to use firebase notification for android oreo

Tags: android

```
    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ProfileResp Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        try {
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());

            String title = data.getString("title");
            String message = data.getString("message");
            //imageUri will contain URL of the image to be displayed with Notification
            String imageUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("trailer_img");
            //To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
            bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(RestURLs.BASE_URL+imageUri);
            sendNotification(title, message, bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

/*
 *To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
 * */
public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return bitmap;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
}
// [END receive_message]

/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 *
 * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String ttl, String messageBody, Bitmap image) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityHome.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", ttl);
    intent.putExtra("message", messageBody);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(ttl)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                    .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

this is my  code . 
by using this code the notifications are displayed in all mobile phones,
 but not in oreo phones .
i aslo updated my firbase dependency .
but still not working

Also i used channel but i dont know how to use it with firebase .
can any one help me to get notifications on oreo based mobile phones.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because repeating the same sentence over and over again is not helpful or constructive. Describe the problem and ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Since android O, google add `NotificationChannel`

> Demonstration of using channels to categorize notifications by topic. This feature was added in Android O, and allows users to have fine-grained control over their notification preferences.

Use this method to return `NotificationCompat.Builder`

```
public NotificationCompat.Builder initChannels(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26) {
        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    }
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default",
            "Channel name",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    channel.setDescription("Channel description");
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "default");
}
```

And be sure to use latest support library.